# why recvfrom() function can receive all of traffic

Tags: icmp

I wrote a ICMP ping code in C, I created a socket by `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)`
 and I bond it as: `bind(sendSock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr))`, after calling `sendto()` function, I called `recvfrom()` function to receive the ICMP reply, but I found I could receive all of packages not only the destIP I sent before.

Why recvfrom() behavior like this? I was a Java programmer, I knew Java socket only receive the package it sent with the specific IP.

Is that any socket could receive all of packages in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `recvfrom` system call, and everything to do with the type of socket you've created.

From the [`raw(7)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html):

> A raw socket can be bound to a specific local address using the
>          `bind(2)` call.  If it isn't bound, all packets with the specified IP
>          protocol are received